# How to find number of paths between 2 nodes of a certain length

Tags: adjacency-matrix

Consider the following adjacency matrix:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I need to find the number of paths (repeated vertices are allowed) from node 8 to node 5 of length 6.

What methods are there? I want to know how to do this by multiplying matrices but no one has given me a good answer.

Comment: the link to the duplicate question is dead

Answer (score 2):

This is done exactly by multiplying the matrix by itself 6 times, and then $A_6[i,j]$ will give you the number of paths. To get the intuition, figure out what a single matrix multiplication does to the adjacency matrix.